# PostgreSql Triggers across databases

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm having a difficult time finding if postgres can insert/update/delete tables across different databases. 
Here is what i want to perform:

- I have two databases: **database_a** and **database_b**
- **database_a** contains a table **table_a**
- **database_b** contains a table **table_a**

I want to update **table_a** in **database_b** with changes made at **table_a** in **database_a**. So table_a in database_b will always contain same data as table_a in database_a.

Can i use triggers to do that? if not, is there any solution?

Comment: Why? Replication is probably a better idea here. There's also a postgres to postgres foreign data wrapper http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan can you please provide me with a tutorial to implement replication using pgadmin 3. thanks

Comment: if you tell me what you're trying to accomplish, sure :)

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan the main goal is to work with a copy of a table in another different database. However if there's any changes in the table of the first database, these changes should be commited in the table of the second database. This way i can work with an updated copy of the first table. i dont want to use one table to avoid referential integrity across databases